# i18next returnObjects in root of file

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

i18next allows you to return the translation in an object rather than only one string of a key using something like: `t('namespace:key1.key2', {returnObjects: true})` However i have yet to find a way to get the root of a namespace as an object. So in this example `t('namespace', {returnObjects: true})` does not return the namespace in an object.

Is there a different way to get this done? Because otherwise i have to wrap every namespace that i have to access like this in a key so i can access it this way.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to get the root like you've mentioned, Why would you want to get the entire namespace?

Comment: @felixmosh I have a namespace with translations of products based on product id, so to dynamically get the translation of multiple products from one category i have to get the root as an object

Comment: For dynamic data (like products) which comes from DB, it is better to expose an API end point, which will return the proper json given product id.
Then configure your i18next to use this API as your go to path of https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend